# Cannot resolve symbol ProcessLifecycleOwner

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentado solucionar este problema: `Cannot resolve symbol ProcessLifecycleOwner` pero no encuentro la manera, he probado a importar `import android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;` sin éxito.

El error me salta en esta parte de mi código:

```
if(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
                        nAdView.show();
                    }else {
                        Log.d("AppInBackground", "App Is In Background Ad Is Not Going To Show");
                    }
```

Esta extraído de aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234180/issue-violation-of-interfering-with-apps-third-party-ads-or-device-functional

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Utilizas android studio verdad? en el import te lo marca como rojo?

Comment: @Wilmer efectivamente, me pasa eso exactamente

Comment: En android studio dale a `Build -> Clean Project` para sincronizar todas las dependencias

Comment: agrega esto a tu gradle  `implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0'`

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias @Wilmer

Comment: de nada, lo pondre como respuesta valida :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esto a tu configuracion gradle

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0' 
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0'
```